# How to combine show and list functions in CouchDB?

Tags: javascript, couchdb

I am trying to study CouchDB. Is there a way to use list functions in a show function, or vice versa? For example, can I call some list function to render a document in its show function? Or call show(id) to render a list if ids in a list function?

Answer (score 1):

As of now, I do not believe there is a direct way to do so.

However, you are able to re-use code (including templates) via [CommonJS modules](http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/CommonJS_Modules). Although you won't be able to call a `_list` through a `_show` function, you can simulate the reverse, and use the same templates/code from a `_show` in your `_list` response.

Answer (score 1):

I believe what you are trying to do is render child entities together with their parent entity. This can be achieved by having the `view` pass both the parent and the children to the `list` function in a particular order.

There is an [example](http://guide.couchdb.org/draft/transforming.html#theory) in the [The Definitive Guide](http://guide.couchdb.org/) for a scenario with multiple parent entities, each having child entities. For the simpler case of only one parent, the `view` may emit the parent entity followed by its children, and the `list` function may go along the lines of:

```
parent_entity = getRow();
/* ... make parent_repr ... */
send(parent_repr);
while (child_entity = getRow()) {
    /* ... make child_repr ... */
    send(child_repr);
}
```

Thus, you do not have to have a separate `show` function for the parent.